# Extra line break between ordered list items

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Question. Is it possible to add an extra line break between list items. par exemple

My current situation. I'm using Rails with bootstrap.

```
  <h1> Things I like </h1>
  <ol>
    <li> Apples </li><br>
    <li> Bananas </li><br>
  </ol>
```

I want that extra line break between my list items but I don't want to have to do the br tag between each. Is it possible through CSS or some special bootstrap class to take care of that?

Comment: Have you tried maybe adding `padding` or `margin` to the <li> items through CSS?

Comment: @Zigzagoon Ahhh that is brilliant. If you give that as an answer I'll accept it. I don't know why I didn't think of that but adding a bootstrap py or my will do exactly what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS file:

```
li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

You can modify the accessor ("li") or the value as you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
li {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

for top, right, bottom, left

or

```
li{
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

for top&bottom, left&right

or just

```
li {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```