# Remove line break created by ordered list html tag

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

I am having issues trying to remove a line break that is created when using ordered list in a automated Outlook email (`<ol>`).

**What I have tried:**

1. to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56138596/extra-line-break-between-ordered-list-items) solution but I am not sure if that can be implemented/read through VBA
2. to replace line breaks with blank spaces to no avail
3. to combine the header line with the ol tag in same line (`& "I want to remove the text between this line and my 1st ordered list <ol>" _`)

**Is there a way to accomplish this using VBA?**

*Code, output, & desired output below:*

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "me@me.com"
        .to = Target.Offset(, 2)
        .cc = Target.Offset(, 3)
        .Subject = "Subject"
        .HTMLBody = "Hello StackOverflow " _
                    & "<br><br>" _
                    & "I want to remove the text between this line and my 1st ordered list" _
                    & "<ol>" _
                    & "<li> Text </li>" _
                    & "<ul>" _
                    & "<li> Bullet </li>" _
                    & "</ul>" _
                    & "<li> More Text </li>" _
                    & "</ol>"
```

---

### What I get:

[image]

---

### What I want:

[image]

---

```
I want to remove the text beween this line and my 1st ordered list
    'I WANT TO REMOVE THE BLANK SPACE HERE
    1.  Text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here is a solution: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/735jfwLu/)*

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
  <!--
  /* Style Definitions */
  p.MsoNormal
   {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    }
   
   
  p.MsoListParagraph
   {mso-style-priority:34;
    margin-top:0in;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:0in;
    margin-left:.5in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    }
  -->
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
 <div class=WordSection1>
  <p>Hello StackOverflow</p>
  <p class=MsoNormal>I want to remove the text between this line and my 1<sup>st</sup> ordered list</p>
  <p class=MsoListParagraph style='text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l1 level1 lfo1'>1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Text</p>
  <p class=MsoListParagraph style='margin-left:74.25pt;text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo2'><span style='font-family:Symbol'>&middot;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bullet</p>
  <p class=MsoListParagraph style='text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l1 level1 lfo1'>2.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;More Text</p>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

*VBA Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .Subject = "Subject"

         ' Body Style
        .HTMLBody = "<html><head><style>" & _
            "<!-- p.MsoNormal" & _
                    "{margin:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt}" & _
                 "p.MsoListParagraph" & _
                     "{mso-style-priority:34;margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:.5in;margin-bottom:.0001pt}" & _
              "--> </style></head>" & _
            "<body>" & _
                "<div class=WordSection1>" & _
                    "<p>Hello StackOverflow</p>" & _
                    "<p class=MsoNormal>I want to remove the text between this line and my 1<sup>st</sup> ordered list</p>" & _
                    "<p class=MsoListParagraph style='text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l1 level1 lfo1'>1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Text</p>" & _
                    "<p class=MsoListParagraph style='margin-left:74.25pt;text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo2'>" & _
                                        "<span style='font-family:Symbol'>&middot;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bullet</p>" & _
                    "<p class=MsoListParagraph style='text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l1 level1 lfo1'>2.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;More Text</p>" & _
                "</div>" & _
            "</body>" & _
        "</html>"

        .Display
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It's quit insane it takes that much code for something so simple

Comment: I try to fix your code but I had to rewrite the `HTML` code, I'm sure you can improve the `HTML` code or write function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use CSS, you can use `margin-top` to remove the space.

Replace `<ol>` with `<ol style="margin-top: 0;">`

Just noticed you want to do it with VBA, but not sure what you mean by this. You can add the change into your VBA but its a HTML rendering thing so VBA doesnt really come into it?

Comment: No change - Also, the quotes interfere so I tried to double quote to correct. Notice in the code I have to embed everything in quotes. & `"<ol style=""margin-top: 0;"">" _` had no impact on output

Comment: I also tried removing the quotes around martin-top and got no change in output

Comment: Also tried `"<ol style=" & Chr(34) & "margin-top: 0;" & Chr(34) & ">"` with no change :(

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at this. Plz don't delete solution - will show others of things that have already been attempted. I plan to bounty this if no solution comes